# Laravel: by using "With" am I avoiding multiple queries/connections into database?

Tags: php, laravel

Take for example the following database structure:

```
Table Sales
id | customer_id | currency_id | number | due_date

Table Open Accounts
id | sale_id | credit | debit | balance
```

Now lets say I want to get all the open accounts:

```
SELECT OpenAccounts::select('oa.*')
    ->from('open_accounts As oa')
    ->join('sales AS sale', 'sale.id', '=', 'oa.sale_id')
    ->where('oa.balance', '>', 0)
    ->orderBy('sale.due_date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

If I want to loop through all the results and print out some data I can do the following:

```
@foreach ($openAccounts as $open)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $open->Sale->due_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $open->Sale->Customer->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ sprintf('%s %s', $open->balance, $open->Sale->Currency->symbol) }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Question**: this means that for each result I'm opening a MySQL connection and querying Sale table, Customer table and Currency table?

Now what If I change the code for:

```
SELECT OpenAccounts::select('oa.*')
    ->with('Sale')
    ->with('Sale.Customer')
    ->with('Sale.Currency')
    ->from('open_accounts As oa')
    ->join('sales AS sale', 'sale.id', '=', 'oa.sale_id')
    ->where('oa.balance', '>', 0)
    ->orderBy('sale.due_date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

By printing the output, I get something like:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [0] => OpenAccounts Object
    (
        [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 89
            [sale_id] => 150
            [debit] => 184.93
            [credit] => 0
            [balance] => 184.93
        )
        [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [Sale] => Sales Object 
            (
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 150
                    [customer_id] => 1
                    [currency_id] => 1
                    [number] => 5
                    [due_date] => '2020-03-08'
                )
                [relations:protected] => Array
                (
                    [Customer] => ...
                    [Currency] => ...
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Question**: Does this mean that now when using for example `$open->Sale->Customer->name` within the loop I'm not initializing a new MySQL connection but yes accessing directly the property returned by the Eloquent Collection?

Comment: Using eager loading, Laravel does an extra query for each eager loaded property. The first is the expected call to the `open_accounts` table, the second will look like `SELECT * FROM sales WHERE account_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, using all the IDs that were pulled in the first query. You're still doing a lot of queries (since you're loading sub relationships as  well) so it might be worth trying to do manually with joins.

Comment: Enabling logging on your database while running these Eloquent queries in Tinker is a great way to find out what's really happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Using `with` makes Laravel do eager loading and it will use less database calls as a result.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the Documentation link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading so I can accept it?
Thanks

Comment: No problem. Updated :)